# MAMP Pro "Starting Apache failed" on PHP 5.5.38

Tags: php, apache, mamp-pro

I have MAMP Pro running successfully using a couple different versions of PHP.  However, when I tried to set up a host with PHP v5.5.38 suddenly Apache wouldn't start and displayed the error...

> Starting Apache failed
>
> Apache couldn't be started. Please check the log file for more information.

There is no information produced in the apache log file and the issue is resolved if I switch back to using one of the PHP versions I already know works.  I tried deleting that version of PHP in `Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php5.5.38/` and then reinstalled it, but I'm still getting the same issue.

[image: MAMP Pro error: Starting Apache failed]

I'm running macOS Sierra v10.12.5 and MAMP Pro 4.1.1.

Comment: check port 80 is blocked by some application or not.

Comment: I've run into the same issue when using a downloaded version of PHP from their site (https://www.mamp.info/en/downloads/) and adding it to the /Applications/MAMP/bin/php folder. Anyone have a solution yet?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue after re-installing MAMP PRO. In addition, all my hostnames turned red. Figured out that they had all lost connection to their SSL Certs. Once I re-created all of the certs (you could relink to existing certs as well), and the hostnames were no longer red, Apache launched just fine.

Answer (score 0):

Solved: The same solution than @Taz (A bit tedious, frankly...)

1. Uninstall MAMP PRO (Menu MAMP PRO > Uninstall MAMP PRO)
2. Erase all old MAMP directories in Applications
3. Install a fresh MAMP PRO copy
4. In the old Mac, make a backup of MAM (select localhost host, menu File > Backup. tick Virtual Hosts and MySQL Databases.
5. In the new Mac, import the backup

NOTE: it could take time to backup, transfer and restore. You have to be patient...

RESTORE THE HOSTS TABLE

Copy /Volumes/*your_user_name*/Library/Application Support/appsolute/MAMP PRO/settings5.plist to the new mac